# program with matrix allocation and collision in text

Tags: c

I tried solving it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    typedef struct
    {
        int r;
        int c;
        char *word;

    } triplet;

    int main()
    {

       triplet *a,aux;
       char **b;
       int j,i,n;
       FILE *f,*g,*p;
       f=fopen("data.txt","r");//Se deschide fisierul text
       g=fopen("outfile.txt","w");
       a=calloc(10,sizeof(triplet));//Se aloca dinamic spatiu pentru structura

       i=0;

       while (!(feof(f)))
       {
          a[i].word=malloc(60);
          fscanf(f,"[ %d %d %s ]\n",&(a[i].r),&(a[i].c),a[i].word);
          i++;
       }

       n=i;
       printf("%d \n",n);

       b = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          b[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(char));

       for(i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
          printf("%d %d %s\n",a[i].r,a[i].c,a[i].word);
       }

       for(i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
          b[i]=realloc(b,a[i].c+strlen(a[i].word)*sizeof(char));
          for(j=0; j<n; j++)
          {
             b[i][j]=' ';

             for(i=0; i<n; i++)
             {
                for(j=0; j<strlen(a[i].word); j++)
                // if ( b[a[i].r,a[i].c+j]==' ')
                   b[a[i].r,a[i].c+j]=a[i].word[j];
                //else printf("collide at... \n");
             } 

             for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                for(j=0; j<n; j++)
                   printf("%c ",b[i][j]);


          }
       }
    }



<!-- end snippet -->

 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
typedef struct
{
    int r;
    int c;
    char *word;

} triplet;

int main()
{

   triplet *a,aux;
   char **b;
   int j,i,n;
   FILE *f,*g,*p;
   f=fopen("data.txt","r");
   g=fopen("outfile.txt","w");
   a=calloc(10,sizeof(triplet));

   i=0;

   while (!(feof(f)))
   {
      a[i].word=malloc(60);
      fscanf(f,"[ %d %d %s ]\n",&(a[i].r),&(a[i].c),a[i].word);
      i++;
   }

   n=i;
   printf("%d \n",n);

   b = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      b[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(char));

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      printf("%d %d %s\n",a[i].r,a[i].c,a[i].word);
   }

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      b[i]=realloc(b,a[i].c+strlen(a[i].word)*sizeof(char));
      for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      {
         b[i][j]=' ';

         for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         {
            for(j=0; j<strlen(a[i].word); j++)
               // if ( b[a[i].r,a[i].c+j]==' ')
               b[a[i].r,a[i].c+j]=a[i].word[j];
               //else printf("collide at... \n");
         }

         for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
               printf("%c ",b[i][j]);
This is what I needed to do: 

      }
   }
}
```

When I tried implementing it it'd would only read structure and how can I dynamically allocate space for the matrix given that I don't know the number of lines.What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great thank you. How could I handle the collision problem? I thought of using an strlen but not sure it will work.

[image]

Comment: Sorry didn't see the image hasn't been posted

Comment: edited it.......

Comment: Why not debugging your code?

Comment: Never use `feof()` in a `while()` loop, it does not do what the posted code is expecting.

Comment: When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  IF not successful, call `perror()` to output your text and the text of why the system thinks the error occurred, to `stderr`.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  When not successful, call `perror()` to output your text and the text of why the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: the first 'snippit' causes the compiler to output 9 warnings, several of which are critical.  the second 'snippit' causs the compiler to output 17 warnings.  The second 'snippit' is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`,at a minimum use;: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: regarding: `a=calloc(10,sizeof(triplet));`  This should be allocating an array of pointer to 'triplets' not allocating an array of instances of the 'triplet' structure.

Comment: suggest just making the initial allocation of `a[]` as a single NULL Then every time a successful call to `fscanf()` is made, `realloc()` the `a[]` to increase the number pointers and set the new pointer to the instance of a 'triplet'  .  Strongly suggest `char *word` be replaced with `char word[60]`

Comment: the `while( #feof(f))`  loop be re-written so the returned value from `fscanf()` (which should be 3) controls the loop, thereby eliminating the call to `feof()`

Comment: per the C standard, the expression: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has not effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression,

Comment: read all the data into an 'extended two dimensional array of instances of the `triplet` struct.   then perform the logic to determine of there are collisions.  perhaps by checking/filling a new array with the words

Comment: You ask the question *"What am I doing wrong?"* and the answer is **far too many things to address in an answer to this question alone**. For a start, you've joined this community, and asked a question without understanding what is expected of a question (described in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help)). That's subtle disrespectful, so... let's start by addressing this behaviour first. **Whenever you join a community, it is expected that you read (and adhere to) the rules, or leave.** I hate to be the bearer of harsh reality here, but do you understand what I'm explaining?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of multiple serious issues broadly covered by [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) which make the answer unlikely to be helpful to anybody, and more likely to set a bad precedent for more of these questions later.

Comment: Not gonna help.  He's only a 2* programmer at this point, though his single letter, FORTRAN77 like syntax is inviting.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. builds the array of source data, from the input file
3. properly checks for errors and if an error occurs, cleans up after itself.
4. leaves it to the OP to add the logic to perform the collision checks
5. leaves it to the OP to add the logic to output the desired results

and now the proposed code:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

struct sTriplet
{
    int r;
    int c;
    char word[40];
};

typedef struct sTriplet triplet;


int main( void )
{

    char line[62];
    triplet *sourceArray = NULL;

    FILE *fin = fopen( "data.txt", "r" );
    if( !fin )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read data.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    size_t lineCount = 0;
    while( fgets( line, sizeof line, fin ) )
    {
        lineCount++;
        triplet *temp = realloc( sourceArray, lineCount*sizeof( triplet ) );
        if( !temp )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            free( sourceArray );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, realloc successful

        sourceArray = temp;

        if( 3 != sscanf( line, "[ %d %d %s ]",
                &(sourceArray[lineCount].r),
                &(sourceArray[lineCount].c),
                sourceArray[lineCount].word) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "parsing of line from input file failed" );
            free( sourceArray );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    char  collisionChecker[ lineCount ][ MAX_LINE_LEN };
    memset( collisionChecker, ' ', MAX_LINE_LEN * lineCount );

    memcpy( &collisionChecker[0], &sourceArray[0], sizeof( triplet ) );

    for( size_t i = 1; i < lineCount; i++ )  // 1 because 0 already set
    {
        // place logic here to check for overlaps and print status
    }

    free( sourceArray );

    // note following loop may output some extra blank lines
    for( size_t i=0; i< lineCount; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", collisionChecker[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than addressing the problems, you've basically just spoonfed (part of) the solution. While I can see that this is good quality source code, do you feel as though this isn't as helpful as it should be?

Comment: ... and if that is the case, do you think it would be more helpful (to the OP) to vote to close the question (without providing a solution)? I mean, what message does this send? "It's okay to ask questions which violate the community guidelines; we'll answer them anyway!"